# Greek Typewriter Font

Tags: fonts, typewriter

I want to use a greek typewriter font. So far I can't manage to find any font of that kind. Can someone tell me where I can find one?

Comment: Do such fonts exist? Can you give an example (even if it is not suitable for use with TeX)? Also, you should specify which TeX engine you are using (TeX, pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX, conTeXt etc.).

Comment: There are plenty of examples:

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28494/how-to-change-the-font-of-a-latex-table-to-typewriter-font

http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/lmoderntypewriter/

Comment: I believe @cfr asks for an example of a typewriter greek font from any place in the internet to show that such fonts even exist. Because obviously he (and me neither) is not aware of seeing that at all. AFAIK, `lmtt` doesn't support greek.

Comment: I know typewriter fonts exist. I've just never come across one for *Greek*. EDIT: Exactly as @tohecz said while I was posting this much less clear comment! Latin Modern does not support Greek at all that I know of. (Except in mathematics - there is no support for Greek text.)

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood what you said. Neither have I but I think that is a fairly good guess that somewhere there should be at least one!

Comment: I am not sure that is a good guess at all. However, it may be so. Could you at least clarify what you mean by 'typewriter'? Do you mean 'monospaced'? Or do you mean 'reminiscent of the output produced by manual typewriters'? Or both? (Note that Latin Modern features *two* typewriter fonts, only one of which is monospaced.)

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean but I suppose that what I want is its output to remind typewriter.

Comment: @Adam I'm not sure if exists a Greek _typewriter_ font. I understood a monospaced font for Greek letters. Take a look [here](http://www.greekfontsociety.gr/pages/en_typefaces20th.html) perhaps you can find one there.

Comment: @Aradnix thanks but I have already checked that website as I use it generally.

Comment: `CMU Typewriter` is certainly a good choice.

Comment: @cfr you could call it >2 if you count lmtt condensed (monospaced)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know at least three of them, that can be used quite easily with `fontspec`  and `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`: Microsoft's `Consolas` and  `Courier New`, and `DejaVu Sans Mono`. They all have monotoniko and polytoniko characters, that you may enter directly if you have a suitable keyboard.

Here is a demo. Note that `Courier New` seems to have problems with `polyglossia` (‘No Greek script loaded for the current font’),  so I loaded `babel`:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
%
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\usepackage{array, tabularx}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\ttfamily}lX}
Minion Pro: & \textbf{Πυθαγόρειο Θεώρημα}\newline
Εν τοις ορθογωνίοις τριγώνοις το από της την ορθήν γωνίαν υποτεινούσης πλευράς τετράγωνον ίσον εστί τοις από των την ορθήν γωνίαν περιεχουσών πλευρών τετραγώνοις. \\

Myriad Pro: & \sffamily \textbf{Πυθαγόρειο Θεώρημα} \newline
Εν τοις ορθογωνίοις τριγώνοις το από της την ορθήν γωνίαν υποτεινούσης πλευράς τετράγωνον ίσον εστί τοις από των την ορθήν γωνίαν περιεχουσών πλευρών τετραγώνοις.\\

Courier New: & \ttfamily
\textbf{Πυθαγόρειο Θεώρημα} \newline
Εν τοις ορθογωνίοις τριγώνοις το από της την ορθήν γωνίαν υποτεινούσης πλευράς τετράγωνον ίσον εστί τοις από των την ορθήν γωνίαν περιεχουσών πλευρών τετραγώνοις\\

DejaVu Sans Mono: & \fontspec{DejaVu Sans Mono} \textbf{Πυθαγόρειο Θεώρημα} \newline
Εν τοις ορθογωνίοις τριγώνοις το από της την ορθήν γωνίαν υποτεινούσης πλευράς τετράγωνον ίσον εστί τοις από των την ορθήν γωνίαν περιεχουσών πλευρών τετραγώνοις\\

Consolas: & \fontspec{Consolas}\textbf{Πυθαγόρειο Θεώρημα} \newline
Εν τοις ορθογωνίοις τριγώνοις το από της την ορθήν γωνίαν υποτεινούσης πλευράς τετράγωνον ίσον εστί τοις από των την ορθήν γωνίαν περιεχουσών πλευρών τετραγώνοις

\end{tabularx}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Amazingly, this comes built into TeX! (EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, this feature does not come from Dr. Knuth, however.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand*\rmdefault{\ttdefault}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
Knuth really planned ahead, since he included a typewriter Greek font
as part of the Computer Modern Typewriter series. 
And now you can use Unicode input:

\textgreek{Ἐν ἀρχῇ ἦν ὁ λόγος, καὶ ὁ λόγος ἦν πρὸς τὸν θεόν, 
καὶ θεὸς ἦν ὁ λόγος.} ---Jn 1:1

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user153012, this is just adding on to your answer to show how to get unicode support, and to clarify that Computer Modern really does support Greek text.

Comment: Why did the `---` become `--`?

Comment: @NVaughan The European Modern Typewriter font has no em-dash ligature. If the call to `T1` is omitted, one would get `---`, because Computer Modern Typewriter has no ligatures except ``!` `` and ``?` ``

Comment: @AndrewCashner Knuth has nothing to do with this; the font used is by Claudio Beccari, part of the CB-fonts distribution.

Comment: @egreg My adoration for DK is diminished slightly, but my love for the LaTeX community is increased! It's amazing how simple this is, and how well integrated with the core defaults.

Comment: When I compile this with xelatex and lualatex I always get empty spaces in place of greek letters. What am I doing wrong? (pdflatex works fine).

Comment: @alfC Those engines treat fonts differently. You can't use the fontenc package, instead you use fontspec and select the font families you need.

Answer (score 6):

If `xelatex` or `lualatex` is an option for you, you can try `TeX Gyre Cursor`, which is a free Courier clone with greek support or `Courier New` which looks even more like a typewriter face. I don't know how to get the later one, since it was already installed on my PC, so it probably comes with Win 7 or Office. Here is an example (I don't speek or write greek, so this is some random text from wikipedia):

```
% !TeX program=lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}
\newfontfamily\ttdifferent{Courier New}

\def\test{Some english words for comparison.
Η σύγχρονη αγγλική γλώσσα, η οποία μερικές φορές χαρακτηρίζεται ως η πρώτη επιστήμης, των επιχειρήσεων, της πολιτικής και της διπλωματίας, της ψυχαγωγίας, της αεροναυτιλίας και της}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily\test

\ttdifferent\test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answrer I will try it and I will see if it is what I want.

Comment: Tex Gyre Cursor does not seem to support accents at all. Notice how ί is missing from χαρακτηρίζεται in the example text. I use Cousine as my editor-font since it supports full polytonic greek while being quite readable (even enjoyable).

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
Let's see some typewriter greek:
\begin{otherlanguage}{greek}
\texttt{Oper Edei Deixai.}
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: perhaps you could add an image of the output, or some description.

Comment: really easy to compile.

Comment: ... if you have access to a compiler.

Comment: and we all know everybody have:
http://www.compileonline.com/try_latex_online.php

Comment: I hadn't used that site before, but had tried sharelatex.  It's not really the point though - when the visual effect of the output is so important most people would post an image (see the other answers here).

Comment: Yes, and some of them are really the same solutions as mine. Ok, I accept it, that pictures are important, but this problem is really easy.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `xetex` or `luatex`, then Frederic Goudy’s Remington Typewriter font (to be precise, only the italic is Goudy’s), in the Pro version published by Lanston, seems to have what you need for both monotonic and polytonic Greek.  You can preview the glyphs at [www.myfonts.com/fonts/lanston/ltc-remington-typewriter/](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/lanston/ltc-remington-typewriter/). The italic has only a little Greek, but the upright seems complete.

The version of Courier from ParaType also supports polytonic Greek: preview the glyphs at [www.myfonts.com/fonts/paratype/courier/](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/paratype/courier/).

Answer (score 0):

It is not immediately  apparent which fonts support Cyrillic and Greek, but you can find a fairly wide assortment of excellent fonts with broad language support if you subscribe to Typekit.

See e.g. the [Typewriter Fonts list](https://typekit.com/lists/typewriter-fonts)

Typekit is a pay service, but you will be supporting typographers. :)

Some of the fonts on Typekit may be licensed for free elsewhere e.g. [Anonymous Pro](http://www.marksimonson.com/fonts/view/anonymous-pro).

Comment: None of those fonts support Greek. (You can check if you click on them and scroll down to 'Language Support' on the right.)

Comment: @cfr It's a good point, I should have mentioned: Some of the Typekit fonts support Greek (e.g. [Source Sans Pro](http://blog.typekit.com/2014/07/09/source-sans-v2/)) but for some reason [do not list it](https://typekit.com/fonts/source-sans-pro). I thought to suggest Typekit, at any rate - just in case.

Comment: Definitely worth mentioning. When you said it was not obvious which supported Greek, I assumed you meant it didn't say and not that it does say but isn't accurate! Strange that they would leave that information out, too. I think it would be worth adding that into your answer when you edit it so that it does not get lost in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The [New Computer Modern fonts package](https://ctan.org/pkg/newcomputermodern) of Antonis Tsolomitis offers this. The Greek is based on cbgreek fonts.
[image: new_computer_modern_mono]