# Changing fontfamily in environment lets pdflatex hang

Tags: fonts, environments, compiling

In a book I defined an individual table as follows:

```
\newenvironment{tbl}[3]%
{%
  %\fontfamily{\sffamily}\selectfont
  % Caption
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    \newcommand{\tblcaption}{}
  \else
    \newcommand{\tblcaption}{\caption{#2}}
  \fi
  % Label
  \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax
    \newcommand{\tbllabel}{}
  \else
    \newcommand{\tbllabel}{\label{#3}}
  \fi
  \footnotesize
  \rowcolors{2}{white}{dark-green!5}
  \begin{longtable}[c]{#1}
}{%
    \hiderowcolors%
    \tblcaption%
    \tbllabel%
  \end{longtable}
  \normalsize
  %\fontfamily{\rmfamily}\selectfont
}
```

When I uncomment the two `\fontfamily` statements, `pdflatex.exe` is running forever. This happens independently of the TeX editor I am using and the TeX distribution (TeX Live and MiKTeX).

I guess that something in the `environment` definition must cause the problem, but I cannot figure out, what that might be.

Comment: Welcome! `\fontfamily` expects something like `phv` as an argument. If you just want the default serif, use `\rmfamily` - no need for `\fontfamily` or `\selectfont`. Similarly for `\sffamily`. If you need more help please post compilable code or code which produces the error when we try to compile it.

Comment: I will give `\sffamily` / `\rmfamily` a try - thank you! I took the code from other postings, that I read about changing the font in an environment.

Comment: Either you misunderstood something or the code you found is erroneous. Do you have a link? If it is on this site, it should be corrected if it is really as you say.

Comment: I read https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28494/how-to-change-the-font-of-a-latex-table-to-typewriter-font - and that made me think that this were the way to go - but I probably misunderstood the thread.

Comment: I think you are just trying to mix bits from different answers/comments which are of different kinds. Note that the example with `\fontfamily{}` uses a name and not a macro in the argument, `pcr`. Moreover, as noted in the comments, just using `\ttfamily` instead of `\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont` would be better (simpler, more flexible, more consistent). Maybe you read the suggestion as saying to just substitute the `pcr` rather than the whole line?

Comment: I've added another comment to the comment suggesting `\ttfamily`. Unfortunately, comments are ephemeral, but some things can't be helped.

Comment: apart from the syntax error in the use of `\fontfamily`  the `\normalsize` and `\selectfont` do nothing at all in that position, you have them at the end of the environment so immediately the environment group will end and the font setting will be discarded before it is used. What is the intention of these commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\rmfamily`, `\sffamily` and `\ttfamily` are self-sufficient font switches. You do not need `\fontfamily` or `\selectfont` with these and they aren't suitable as arguments to `\selectfont`.

`\fontfamily` expects the name of a font family e.g. `phv`, `clm2dj` or `AnnSton`. You can't give it an argument which is itself a font-switching macro.

So just use

```
\sffamily
```

and

```
\rmfamily
```

alone.

If you need further help, please post code for a minimal document we can compile to reproduce the problem.